# Java 8 Date and Time Temporal Field

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I navigation across Java 8 Date and Time new API and i couldn't go any further and i cannot find any good resource in the web i hope you be kindle with this question.

My simple source code is

```
final LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
date.get(TemporalField field)
```

And i get the source code and i see.

```
public int get(TemporalField field)
  Gets the value of the specified field from this date as an int.
```

My question is how i can get a TemporalField or which is the easiest way to get this code to work..

```
final int value = date.get(????);
```

This works thanks to JB Nizet

```
date.get(java.time.temporal.ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

API.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html
```

Comment: Look at the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html. Just below the type name, it says: *All known implementing classes: ChronoField*

Comment: Yep but i need a running example :( because i have try...  date.get(ChronoField.???); and not seems to work....

Comment: Then put the code you tried in your question, and define precisely what "not seems to work" means.

Comment: Now it works.....Sorry Java 8 Date and Time is the new API i have more problems with because i didn't study it yet.. sorry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get instances of [`TemporalField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html).

Firstly, the enum [`ChronoField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) implements `TemporalField` and contains various constants.

```
ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

Secondly, the classes [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) and [`JulianFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html) contain static `TemporalField` objects.

```
IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR;
JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY;
```

Thirdly, the class [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) contains static `TemporalField` objects and methods to create `TemporalField` objects based off WeekFields.

```
WeekFields.WEEK_BASED_YEARS;
WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.weekOfMonth();
```

Comment: I pick your answer because have important and additional and very good information...

Answer (score 5):

The Javadoc of TemporalField says, right there:

"The most commonly used units are defined in ChronoField. Further fields are supplied in IsoFields, WeekFields and JulianFields. Fields can also be written by application code by implementing this interface."

Pick what you want to get out from those fields.